# How to lock Hybris to Initialize System on Production Environment

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there any way to lock Hybris by Initializing System accidentally on Production Environment. It is too risky if some one mistakenly click on initialize button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use this setting in our local.properties on the production system to avoid the running system from being initialized accidentally from the administration page:

> system.unlocking.disabled=true

Hybris highly recommend to use this setting once you have your system up and running.

Comment: Obviously, you will need to lock the system every time after deployment with this approach.

Comment: If you do it in the local.properties the settings should persist imo.

Answer (score 3):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860234/2478134), let me tell other ways to achieve this.

### Lock the system initialization using properties

To lock the system for initialization and update add the unlocking (`system.unlocking.disabled=true`) properties to your `local.properties` file and rebuild your system.

### Block/Redirect URL from the web server

If you have a web server in place for admin console, You can block or redirect `/hac/platform/initURL` to some dummy URL(`/hac/platform/NOinit`) from the web server itself. Do the google for your web server configuration for the same.

### Change request mapping in Hybris HAC(Not recommend):

HAC request mapping is done by `defaultHacConfiguration.json` file. You can change the request mapping itself.

```
{
    "path" : "/NOinit",
    "label" : "initialization",
    "skipPrefix" : false
  }
```

---

### Refer the [detailed post here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/02/block-prevent-system-initialization-production-hybris.html)