# Block or disable init url in Hybris

Tags: initialization, sap-commerce-cloud

Is there a way we can redirect `/hac/platform/init` to a Hybris `404` like how it happens for `/hac/platform/init/execute`? Also guide me with the ant targets that I must use to see the changes that I make on **init.jsp** and **init.js** (they don't go live on fly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want to protect the initialization trigger, which could be accidental.

Hybris OOTB you can lock the HAC system initialization.

To lock the system for initialization and update add the unlocking (`system.unlocking.disabled=true`) properties to your `local.properties` file and rebuild your system.

You can also unlock it without restarting the system.

- Set system.unlocking.disabled to false (HAC>configuration)
- Go to `/hac/platform/init`, Click on Unlock.

[Refer blog](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/02/block-prevent-system-initialization-production-hybris.html) for more details and other ways to block the URL itself - Answering your actual question.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'd like to get rid of the init url itself, because after initializing a project, I'd never require myself or anyone to re-initialize it whatsoever. So why need that URL ?

Comment: Locking system initialization is what can be done OOTB, but if you want to block URL itself, then that could be done many ways. let me update the answer.

Comment: Redirecting seems to be the right one for my scenario. Great answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

Lock system initialization screen and protect it by setting system.unlocking.disabled=true

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'd like to get rid of the init url itself, because after initializing a project, I'd never require myself or anyone to re-initialize it whatsoever. So why need that URL ?